# How to make image clipping in css

Tags: html, css, image-clipping

I tried to make an clipping mask on css but I think I'm on a wrong track. Here is the image that im trying to convert to html..

[image]

now that I tried it on my end, it looks like a mess:
[image]

**CSS:**

```
.img_nav_individual {
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-left: 8px;
    outline: 1px solid #c1cacf;
    max-width: 96px;
}

.img_nav_individual img { clip: rect(10px, 290px, 190px, 10px); }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img_nav_individual"> <img src="img/parents1.png" />
  <div class="image_nav_text"> <span>parents</span> </div>
</div>
```

Suggestions are very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for easy test

Comment: use overflow: hidden; in .img_nav_individual class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `overflow:hidden;` attribute on img_nav_individual. That will help here is your example : http://jsfiddle.net/6wPvW/

Answer (score 1):

Either use `overflow:hidden;` on the outer element or set the image as a background image to achieve what you are after.

If you want to use clip, then the image needs to have `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` properties to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe after looking both the images that we need to do this

```
 <div class="img_nav_individual"> 
  <img src="img/parents1.png" align="right" />
  <div class="image_nav_text"> 
  <span>parents</span> </div>
 </div>
```

If you notice I have added `align="right"` to img tag

Answer (score 0):

I know I should focus on code/technical. But I have a opinion, that why you not try crop these images before use it on html page? I think this way is simple and fast to go ahead!